# Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't recgonize m CPU correctly

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, cpu, amd-processor

My computer is running ubuntu 12.04 (64bit), and I have a AMD Athlon(tm) X4 760K Quad Core Processor which is about 3.8ghz (and an Radeon HD 7770 GPU). Yet, when I type in `cat /proc/cpuinfo` - I get:

```
    processor   : 0
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 21
model       : 19
model name  : AMD Athlon(tm) X4 760K Quad Core Processor
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x6001119
cpu MHz     : 1800.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 16
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 tce nodeid_msr tbm topoext perfctr_core arat cpb hw_pstate npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold bmi1
bogomips    : 7599.97
TLB size    : 1536 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm 100mhzsteps hwpstate cpb eff_freq_ro

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 21
model       : 19
model name  : AMD Athlon(tm) X4 760K Quad Core Processor     
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x6001119
cpu MHz     : 1800.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 17
initial apicid  : 1
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 tce nodeid_msr tbm topoext perfctr_core arat cpb hw_pstate npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold bmi1
bogomips    : 7599.97
TLB size    : 1536 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm 100mhzsteps hwpstate cpb eff_freq_ro

processor   : 2
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 21
model       : 19
model name  : AMD Athlon(tm) X4 760K Quad Core Processor     
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x6001119
cpu MHz     : 1800.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 18
initial apicid  : 2
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 tce nodeid_msr tbm topoext perfctr_core arat cpb hw_pstate npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold bmi1
bogomips    : 7599.97
TLB size    : 1536 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm 100mhzsteps hwpstate cpb eff_freq_ro

processor   : 3
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 21
model       : 19
model name  : AMD Athlon(tm) X4 760K Quad Core Processor     
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x6001119
cpu MHz     : 1800.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 19
initial apicid  : 3
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 tce nodeid_msr tbm topoext perfctr_core arat cpb hw_pstate npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold bmi1
bogomips    : 7599.97
TLB size    : 1536 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm 100mhzsteps hwpstate cpb eff_freq_ro
```

The important part of all this being, `cpu MHz     : 1800.000` which indicates that I have only 1.8ghz of processing power, which is totally wrong. Is it something with drivers or Ubuntu?? Also, will windows recognize all of my processing power? Thanks!

(NOTE: My cpu doesn't have intigrated graphics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's being reported is the dynamic clock speed. Due to [dynamic frequency scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_frequency_scaling), your clock speed should only be at 3.8GHz under heavy load. Both Ubuntu and Windows will handle this similarly.

Note that you should be able to set your idle clock speed in the BIOS, but 1800 MHz is a perfectly reasonable setting.

Comment: so when i play games, it goes up?

Comment: Yes, gaming should tax a CPU core enough to scale it to a higher frequency. If you're interested in seeing up-to-date system stats (mem usage, clock freq, temps, disk I/O, etc.), you may be interested in setting up [conky](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpConky)